# Redirect everyone except my ip to a file

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to ensure that everyone is redirected to my `/splash` folder except for my own IP ... but the only scripts I can find are ones that deal with a single file. I need to ignore the files within the `/splash` folder because I need to be able to show a logo on the splash page...

Here's my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.345.67.89
RewriteRule !^(splash$|images/|style/) splash [L]
```

What should be modified or included to Redirect everyone except my ip to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why so many downvotes on this question.

Add a `R` flag for redirection and some correction in your regex:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12\.345\.67\.89$
RewriteRule !^(splash|images|style)(/|$) /splash [L,NC,R]
```

This should be first rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`.

Comment: I dont either... just an honest question. So I've done this... but it just won't work for my IP. I just keep getting directed to the splash folder.

Comment: This is fairly simple rule and I have tested it also. If your IP is correct in this rule then it wont redirect to `/splash` page. Check your external IP and make sure you have it here correctly.